# Closure/scope JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, closures

I'm trying to group some exisiting top-level functions inside a
closure (to avoid polluting the global namespace) but I'm not quite
getting it to work.

First, all the JS works outside my anonymous function, but once I put
it in the anonymous function I get an error of "crossfade is not
defined". Does anyone see anything completely obvious that I am
missing?

I'm not quite getting why the the setInterval/crossfade works outside
the anonymous function but not inside. Anything inside start() should
be able to see vars/functions outside start() and it should all be
protected in the closure created by the top-level anonymous function?
I'm not trying to access anything *within* crossfade(), I'm just
trying to execute it.

```
(function($) {

    //vars up here that internal functions can access
    //also using some jquery inside here, so using $

    function crossfade() {
        //body here
    }

    //other functions

    function start() {
        //body here

         cInterval = setInterval('crossfade()', 5000);
    } 

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `setInterval` method will be run in the scope of the window, so the crossfade function doesn't exist there. You have to make an anonymous function so that a closure is created that contains a reference to the function:

```
cInterval = window.setInterval(function() { crossfade(); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `setInterval('crossfade()', 5000);` doesn't create a closure - it creates a string to be `eval()`d.  You should use a function instead:

```
setInterval(function() { crossfade(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: I'd use setInterval(crossfade,5000);

Answer (score 2):

When `setInterval` is passed a string, the string is evaluated in global scope. That explains why `crossfade` is not visible when `setInterval` fires.

`setInterval` can also be passed a function reference:

```
setInterval(crossfade, 5000);
```

in which case your code will work as expected, since `crossfade` is visible at the point where you call `setInterval`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, but I get an error about it not being called with quotes.

Comment: The preferred way is without the quotes. What error message did you get, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid polluting the global scope, you can do a few things:

- Extend jQuery, since you're already using jQuery. (Use jQuery as a namespace.)
- Create a single object to hold your methods. (Create your own namespace.)