# Using closures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I have come across this javascript code.

```
var digit_name = function() {
    var names = ['zero', 'one','two'];
    return function(n) {
        return names[n];
    };
}();

alert(digit_name(1));
```

The output is **one**. I understand that the inner function is being assigned to the variable **digit_name**. What is the need for adding parentheses in the 6th line after the code of outer function. Can anyone tell what exactly is going on?

Comment: Search for "javascript self invoking function" e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367988/javascript-self-invoking-function

Comment: The `names` variable is local to the anonymous function

Comment: What happens if you remove the parentesis on line 6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript syntax: function calls and using parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593509/javascript-syntax-function-calls-and-using-parenthesis) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript

Comment: [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: check this post in order to understand closures and scope in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792170/closure-scope-javascript-jquery

Comment: This is called the "module pattern" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ending `()` you see make that outer function execute immediately. So `digit_name` ends up storing the resulting inner function, as opposed to a pointer to the outer function.

For more information see: [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9):

The added parentheses  makes the outer function execute, if you omit it it will assign outer function to your `digit_name` instead of the inner function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's give some names to these functions to better understand what's going on:

```
var digit_name = function outer() {
    var names = ['zero', 'one','two'];
    return function inner(n) {
        return names[n];
    };
}();

alert(digit_name(1));
```

So, there are two functions at play here: `inner` and `outer`. You're defining a function called `outer`, whose purpose is to create a closure scope capturing the `names` array, and defining and returning another function that has access to this closure. The parentheses at line 6 mean *call the function*, so the value that gets assigned to the `digit_names` variable isn't the *outer* function, but the *inner* one.

Answer (score 1):

`var digit_name = function() {...};`  => `digit_name` is a function

`var digit_name = function() {...}();` => `digit_name` is an object returned by the function

Answer (score 0):

```
var digit_name = function() { // Create outer function
    var names = ['zero', 'one','two']; // Define names array, this is done when the outer function is ran
    return function(n) { // Return the new inner function, which gets assigned to digit_name
        return names[n];
    };
}(); // Execute the outer function once, so that the return value (the inner function) gets assigned to digit_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two very quick processes here.

If we were to write this:

```
function makeDigitReader () { var names; return function (n) { return names[n]; }; }
var myDigitReader = makeDigitReader();
```

You would correctly guess that myDigitReader would be given the inner function.

What they're doing is skipping a step.
By adding the parentheses, what they're doing is firing the function the instant that it's defined.

So you're getting this happening:

```
var myDigitReader = function () {
    var names = [...];
    return function (n) { return names[n]; };
};

myDigitReader = myDigitReader();
```

See what's happened?
You've returned the inner function as the new value to what used to be the outer function.
So the outer function doesn't exist anymore, but the inner function still has access to the `names` array.

You can return an object instead of a function, as well.
And those object properties/functions would have access to what was initially inside of the function, as well.

Normally, you will either see these immediately-invoking functions wrapped in parentheses `var myClosure = (function() { return {}; }());`.

If you intend to run one without assigning its return to a value, then you need to put it in parentheses, or add some sort of operand to the front of it, to make the compiler evaluate it.

```
!function () { doStuffImmediately(); }(); // does stuff right away
function () { doStuffImmediately(); }(); // ***ERROR*** it's an unnamed function
```

Hope that answers all of the questions you might have.